# Git, how to reference branching point from current branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch

Is there a magic variable in Git to reference the commit where current branch was created? For example I want to show commits only in the current branch after the point where history was branched. Of course I could skim the log to find branching point and command something like `master..head`, but this doesn't work if the branch has already merged to master. I want to be able to view commits introduced in current branch more generally, regardless if it's merged or not, and show only these commits rather than deducing it from full log graph.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no reference to the original commit. Branches in Git are just pointers to the current commit.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you could find it out if the reflog is complete.

```
git reflog <branch>
```

The earliest reflog records what you want.

If you really need this feature, you'd better always make a tag when you create a new branch. And ask all the team members to follow this rule.